# MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync() resumes app from splash screen

Tags: android, maui

I'm quite new to MAUI and I've been experiencing this problem when accessing either the `CapturePhotoAsync()` or `PickPhotoAsync()` methods of MediaPicker:

The app is sent to background when opening the camera or the gallery, and once the taken photo or the chosen one are confirmed the app is resumed but it's sent back to its splash screen resulting in the caller method being unable to complete.

This happens on Android devices, about 95% of the times on physical device (I'm testing it on a Redmi with Android 11.0 API 30), less frequently on emulators (tested both on Android 11.0 API 30 and 13.0 API 33).

I can't tell about iOS because I haven't tested it yet.

Here's a sample of my code (that sits in a ViewModel inside a RelayCommand):

```cs
public partial class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    readonly IMediaPicker mediaPicker;
    readonly IMediaPicker someService;
    public MyViewModel(IMediaPicker _mediaPicker, IMediaService _someService){
          mediaPicker = _mediaPicker;
          someService = _someService;
    }

    //...

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task TakePhotoAsync(ObjVM someObject)
    {
        try
        {
            if (mediaPicker.IsCaptureSupported)
            {
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                    FileResult chosenPhoto = await mediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
                    if (chosenPhoto != null)
                    {
                        await someService.SaveThePictureAndOtherStuff(chosenPhoto, someObject.Id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "Unable to take the picture", "Ok");
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "This device is not enabled to take the pictures", "Ok");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

When the camera opens, at line `FileResult chosenPhoto = await mediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();`, the debugger stops and when I confirm the photo taken or the one picked from the gallery the app doesn't resume where I left but it restarts from its splash screen. This happens regardless whether I'm debugging or not. Am I doing something wrong here?

I've been struggling with this for a while now and searched all over the internet, but I've found no solution, can anyone help me please?

This is what my device's log says:

```
07-25 12:01:26.159 Xiaomi M2006C3LVG Info 1255 ActivityManager Force stopping com.myapp.app appid=10281 user=999: from process:17304
07-25 12:01:26.150 Xiaomi M2006C3LVG Info 1255 ActivityManager Force stopping com.myapp.app appid=10281 user=0: from process:17304
07-25 12:01:26.044 Xiaomi M2006C3LVG Debug 16860 CAM_CameraIntentManager    intent calling package is com.myapp.app
07-25 12:01:26.039 Xiaomi M2006C3LVG Verbose 1255 OneTimePermissionUserManager Importance changed for com.myapp.app (10281). importance=1000
07-25 12:01:26.037 Xiaomi M2006C3LVG Verbose 1255 OneTimePermissionUserManager Importance changed for com.myapp.app (10281). importance=1000
07-25 12:01:26.017  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    583 libPowerHal [perfNotifyAppState] pack:com.myapp.app, pid:16330, STATE_DEAD
07-25 12:01:26.005  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Warning 1255    InputDispatcher Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '8a06ba5 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity (server)'
07-25 12:01:26.005  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    WindowManager   WIN DEATH: Window{8a06ba5 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity}
07-25 12:01:25.997  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    ActivityManager Process com.myapp.app (pid 16330) has died: svc   +1 IMPB
07-25 12:01:25.996  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Warning 1255    InputDispatcher Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '63b7991 com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity (server)'
07-25 12:01:25.996  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    WindowManager   WIN DEATH: Window{63b7991 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity}
07-25 12:01:25.921  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Debug   16860   CAM_CameraIntentManager intent calling package is com.myapp.app
07-25 12:01:25.892  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    364 lowmemorykiller Kill 'com.myapp.app' (16330), uid 10281, oom_adj 501 to free 157760kB; reason: device is not responding
07-25 12:01:22.688  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Error   16860   CAM_CameraIntentManager checkCallerLegality: Unknown caller: com.myapp.app
07-25 12:01:22.688  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Debug   16860   CAM_CameraIntentManager The caller:com.myapp.app
07-25 12:01:21.051  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Error   16860   CAM_CameraIntentManager checkCallerLegality: Unknown caller: com.myapp.app
07-25 12:01:21.051  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Debug   16860   CAM_CameraIntentManager The caller:com.myapp.app
07-25 12:01:20.967  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher Window went away: com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0
07-25 12:01:20.964  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    622 BufferQueue [com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0](this:0xea5f6f80,id:587,api:1,p:-1,c:-1) onDestructor()
07-25 12:01:20.964  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    622 BufferQueueConsumer [com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0](id:26e0000024b,api:0,p:-1,c:622) disconnect()
07-25 12:01:20.959  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Verbose 1255    OneTimePermissionUserManager    Importance changed for com.myapp.app (10281). importance=200
07-25 12:01:20.947  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.918  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Error   16860   CAM_CameraIntentManager checkCallerLegality: Unknown caller: com.myapp.app
07-25 12:01:20.918  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Debug   16860   CAM_CameraIntentManager The caller:com.myapp.app
07-25 12:01:20.880  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.874  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Verbose 1255    OneTimePermissionUserManager    Importance changed for com.myapp.app (10281). importance=400
07-25 12:01:20.873  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Verbose 1255    OneTimePermissionUserManager    Importance changed for com.myapp.app (10281). importance=400
07-25 12:01:20.865  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.864  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Error   16860   CAM_CameraIntentManager checkCallerLegality: Unknown caller: com.myapp.app
07-25 12:01:20.864  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Debug   16860   CAM_CameraIntentManager The caller:com.myapp.app
07-25 12:01:20.848  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher Window went away: com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0
07-25 12:01:20.848  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.846  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    622 BufferQueue [com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0](this:0xe9e1df80,id:590,api:1,p:-1,c:-1) onDestructor()
07-25 12:01:20.846  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    622 BufferQueueConsumer [com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0](id:26e0000024e,api:0,p:-1,c:622) disconnect()
07-25 12:01:20.845  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    622 BufferQueueProducer [com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0](id:26e0000024b,api:1,p:16330,c:622) disconnect(): api=1
07-25 12:01:20.748  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.745  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    622 BufferQueueProducer [com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0](this:0xea5f6f80,id:587,api:1,p:16330,c:622) queueBuffer: fps=1.37 dur=1456.12 max=810.60 min=645.53
07-25 12:01:20.716  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    622 BufferQueueProducer [com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0](id:26e0000024e,api:1,p:16330,c:622) disconnect(): api=1
07-25 12:01:20.659  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Warning 16330   Looper  PerfMonitor looperActivity : package=com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity time=43ms latency=655ms running=35ms  procState=2 ClientTransaction{ lifecycleRequest=android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem } historyMsgCount=66 (msgIndex=1 wall=456ms seq=1396 running=185ms runnable=12ms late=621ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver) (msgIndex=9 wall=111ms seq=1404 running=89ms runnable=8ms late=628ms h=android.os.Handler c=mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor) (msgIndex=10 wall=92ms seq=1405 running=81ms runnable=9ms late=739ms h=android.os.Handler c=mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor)
07-25 12:01:20.467  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.450  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.434  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.417  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.400  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.384  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.367  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.351  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.334  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.318  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.302  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.286  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.270  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.253  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.238  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.219  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.203  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.187  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.182  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Warning 16330   Looper  PerfMonitor looperActivity : package=com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity time=6ms latency=782ms running=6ms  procState=2 ClientTransaction{ lifecycleRequest=android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem } historyMsgCount=99 (msgIndex=1 wall=306ms seq=1303 running=150ms runnable=22ms io=26ms late=4841ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159) (msgIndex=94 wall=456ms seq=1396 running=185ms runnable=12ms late=621ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver)
07-25 12:01:20.174  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Warning 16330   Looper  PerfMonitor looperActivity : package=com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity time=3ms latency=778ms running=1ms  procState=2 ClientTransaction{ callbacks=[android.app.servertransaction.TopResumedActivityChangeItem] } historyMsgCount=98 (msgIndex=1 wall=306ms seq=1303 running=150ms runnable=22ms io=26ms late=4841ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159) (msgIndex=94 wall=456ms seq=1396 running=185ms runnable=12ms late=621ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver)
07-25 12:01:20.169  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.154  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.138  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.126  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    622 BufferQueueProducer [com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0](id:26e0000024e,api:1,p:16330,c:622) connect(): api=1 producerControlledByApp=false
07-25 12:01:20.120  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.105  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper} 
07-25 12:01:20.102  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    WindowManager   Relayout Window{8a06ba5 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 com.myapp.app/crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity}: oldVis=4 newVis=0 focusMayChange = true
07-25 12:01:20.087  Xiaomi M2006C3LVG   Info    1255    InputDispatcher setInputWindows displayId=0 Window{519b312 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{53849d6 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 RoundCorner} Window{6ff4b78 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{822c687 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 StatusBar} Window{f604617 mode=1 rootTaskId=131 u0 Splash Screen com.android.camera} com.myapp.app/crc64817921e72d86ace4.MainActivity#0 Window{77af3af mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.MiuiKeyguardPictorialWallpaper} Window{c659d86 mode=1 rootTaskId=1 u0 com.miui.miwallpaper.wallpaperservice.ImageWallpaper}
```

Comment: When the app "resumes from splash screen", there may be an exception occurring. Instead of using `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`, you should try with `await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => {});` instead and wrap that call with a try-catch-block to see if there's an exception. It would also be helpful to see more of your code, show at least the command implementation. The MediaPicker is a control and the ViewModel shouldn't know anything about it. Where is the `mediaPicker` object defined? Try moving the `PickPhotoAsync()` call to the page's code-behind.

Comment: @Julian I've edited my question adding some more code to show how I originally implemented it, so you can see where the `mediaPicker` object comes from. Despite being enclosed in a try-catch block it never threw any exception. It's like when the app is sent to background in favor of the camera it gets killed by the android OS. I'm gonna try to use `MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync` as you suggested and see what comes out and I'll be back to you. Thank you in advance.

Comment: May need to isolate the cause, with some experiments. Make a very simple app, and test the code there. First, with no splash screen. Then, add a splash screen. Do those both work?

Comment: @Julian and @ToolmakerSteve: checking out the device log file (logcat): `Xiaomi M2006C3LVG Info 364 lowmemorykiller Kill 'com.myapp.app' (31322), uid 10280, oom_adj 501 to free 186220kB; reason: device is not responding`. This happens when the camera opens, so I get it's android OS that's killing my app due to lack or ram?

Comment: Your code may very well throw an exception, it's just never handled, because your try-catch-block runs out of scope before the exception occurs. That's because you're using `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` instead of awaiting the async version of it called `MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync()`. It's not necessarily a lack of RAM.

Comment: I've added an answer. Even if it doesn't instantly fix your issue, it should make tracing the problem easier. Please add the output of the device log to the question. Are you using your regular mobile device for development? Development builds require a lot of memory for debugging and instrumentation.

Comment: The command binding with the command parameter should still work with my solution below.

Comment: @Julian yes i'm using my regular mobile phone, the problem occasionally happened also when using emulators (the app would not close but the camera button to take the picture would freeze and got disabled). I switched from `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` to `MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync()` and the thing definitely improved, but after taking 2 or 3 pictures the lowmemorykiller kicks in again. I'm now trying your solution, the lowmemorykiller still happens and no exception gets thrown. I'm going to paste the log to my question as you requested.

Comment: It does indeed seem that it's a memory issue. What are the specs of the phone you are using? I haven't seen anything like this before. What else is your app doing?

Comment: @Julian It's a Xiaomi with 2gb of ram, Octa-core 2Ghz cpu, android version 11. My app is not doing very much at the stage we're talking, you have created a new evaluation filling in some data, then navigated to the pictures list view, where there's a list of 9 pictures and for each one you can either take a photo or choose one from your phone gallery, once you do that the pic gets saved to the app storage and persisted on db (LiteDb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. You're using `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` which cannot be awaited, thus your try-catch block will potentially run out of scope before any exception occurs and then the exception goes unhandled; the correct way would be to `await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync()`
2. The code is breaking the MVVM pattern, because the ViewModel knows about a View control, the MediaPicker in this case, which makes the code difficult to test (with regards to unit and integration tests) and also leads to the use of the `MainThread` methods from 1.

My recommendation is to move any UI related code out of the ViewModel and into the Page's code-behind. That way, you don't break the MVVM pattern while at the same time keeping the UI work on the UI thread. You'll be able to await the call to `MediaPicker.Default.PickPhotoAsync()` and catch any exceptions that may occur.

One way to solve this is to use a delegate to invoke UI functionality from within the ViewModel without breaking the MVVM pattern:

## ViewModel

```cs
public partial class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public delegate Task<FileResult> SelectPhotoDelegate();
    public SelectPhotoDelegate SelectPhotoAsync = null;

    readonly IMediaService _someService;
    public MyViewModel(IMediaService _someService)
    {
          _someService = someService;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task TakePhotoAsync(ObjVM someObject)
    {
        if(SelectPhotoAsync == null) return;

        if(await SelectPhotoAsync() is FileResult chosenPhoto)
        {
            // do something with photo, e.g.:
            await _someService.SaveThePictureAndOtherStuff(chosenPhoto, someObject.Id);

            return;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("log some error here, maybe");
    }
}
```

If necessary, you can also pass the command parameter or any other argument to the `SelectPhotoAsync()` delegate. For that, you just need to declare it in the signature:

```cs
public delegate Task<FileResult> SelectPhotoDelegate(object argument);
```

## Code-behind

```cs
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage(MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel.SelectPhotoAsync = SelectPhotoAsync;
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    private async Task<FileResult> SelectPhotoAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
            {
                if (await MediaPicker.Default.PickPhotoAsync() is FileResult chosenPhoto)
                {
                    return chosenPhoto;
                }

                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "Unable to take the picture", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "This device is not enabled to take the pictures", "Ok");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

There is no need for using `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` or `MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync()` here, because a Page already executes code on the main thread in .NET MAUI.

***Note:** This will not necessarily solve the issue with the crash directly, but it may help in debugging and finding the cause of the crash.*

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted anyways cause although it doesn't solve the issue, it provides a good design concept. The issue is caused by a lack of memory on the physical device, so it was not in the code or in Maui or anything else. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No Bruno, It's not  caused by a lack of memory. It's a common issue in MAUI, many of us faced it. things are not stable in MAUI.